# Using OAuth 2.0 How to get Google drive access from WEBAPI Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have Created ASP.NET WEBAPI Project,then i added one APIController I created One Method for Get Google Drive Files .I refer this link https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc.
when i create **ASP.NET MVC Application** it working fine but when i Create New Project **ASP.NET WEBAPI it not working** the reason is :

```
 var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
            AuthorizeAsync(CancellationToken.None);
```

In Above line AuthorizationCodeMvcApp Takes Argument this = Current Controller and It inherited from  **System.web.mvc Controller**,But in WEB API Project it 
**ApiController System.Web.Http**

How Can i work with APIController?
DO i need to change way to Authatication?

**Note:*in Google Devdeloper Account i have Select O-Auth Client Id then  Type WEB-APPLICATION***

Comment: I haven't tried your C# implementation but Drive API has a .NET Quickstart that may provide you insight from OAuth process to making API calls. There's also the [.NET Client library for Drive API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth).

Comment: I have check link but i haven't find anything related to Inside API Google Drive Access,I can find Only Use in Console Application and Asp.Net Web Application but my requirement is WEBAPI